# python/mysql: SELECTing from multiple tables overwriting duplicate column in resulting dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am coding with Python 3.8.5, and mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB.

I have three tables, `customer`, `partner` and `customer_partner`,

- `customer` has columns `customer_id`, `customer_name`, **`address`**;
- `partner` has columns `partner_id`, `partner_name`, **`address`**; (note the `address` column appears in both tables, but obviously different content)
- `customer_partner` has columns `customer_id`, `partner_id`, describing the partnership between one customer and one partner;

I am trying to fetch joined columns of `customer` and `partner` for customers whose `customer_id` is in a list with following python code and SQL statement:

```
db = connect(...)
cur = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
customer_id_tuple = (1, 2, 3)
sql = f"""SELECT *
    FROM customer, partner, customer_partner
    WHERE 
        customer.customer_id in ({','.join(['%s' for _ in range(len(customer_id_list))])})
        AND customer.customer_id=customer_partner.customer_id 
        AND customer_partner.partner_id=partner.partner_id
    """
cur.execute(sql, customer_id_tuple))
data = cur.fetchall()
```

In the result dictionary `data`, I only see one `address` column. Obviously, `address` from `partner` table overwrites the one from `customer` table.

Besides modifying the column names, do I have a more decent way to avoid such overwriting behavior? Like automatically inserting the table name in front of the column name, like `customer.address` and `partner.address`?

Comment: Always qualify the column names with the table names/aliases and set aliases to column names to avoid these problems.

Comment: And use explicit JOINS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * ...` may lead to ambiguities when there are conflicting column names.
You should set aliases for conflicting column names.
Also set short aliases for the table names that can shorten the code and make it more readable and use them to qualify all the column names.
The implicit join syntax that you use has been replaced, since many years, by explicit join syntax.
Your code should be written like this:

```
sql = f"""
SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.address customer_address,
       p.partner_id, p.partner_name, p.address partner_address
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_partner cp ON c.customer_id = cp.customer_id 
INNER JOIN partner p ON cp.partner_id = p.partner_id
WHERE c.customer_id IN ({','.join(['%s' for _ in range(len(customer_id_list))])})
"""
```

I left out all the columns of `customer_partner` from the `SELECT` list because they are not needed.